# How to apply background-color css for jquery dialog

Tags: jquery

I am forming some morel pop up at run time like below, but i want to apply the background color css how to apply it?

```
$("<div></div>")
                .addClass("dialog1")
                .attr("id", $(this).attr("id"))
                .appendTo("body")
               // .addCss("background-color","red")
                .dialog({
                    title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
                    close: function () { $(this).remove() },
                    width: $(this).attr("data-dialog-width"),
                    modal: true,
                    position: 'center',
                    resizable: $(this).attr("data-dialog-resizable")
                }).load(url);

                $(".close").live("click", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    // $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
                    $(this).closest(".dialog1").dialog("close");
                });
```

Comment: have you tried using `.css()`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) instead of`addCss`:

```
.css("background-color","red")
```

as well as `live()` is deprecated, you should use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead

Comment: as above will be required to call at all the places where ever dialog is initiated in the site we can easily override the css for all dialog.

Answer (score 0):

use `.css()`

```
 $("<div></div>")
            .addClass("dialog1")
            .attr("id", $(this).attr("id"))
            .appendTo("body")
            .css("background-color","red")
            .dialog({
                title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
                close: function () { $(this).remove() },
                width: $(this).attr("data-dialog-width"),
                modal: true,
                position: 'center',
                resizable: $(this).attr("data-dialog-resizable")
            }).load(url);
```

and use `on()` instead of `live()`

```
            $(".close").on("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                // $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
                $(this).closest(".dialog1").dialog("close");
            });
```

delegate it ,if you are attaching this to dynamically generated element..

```
    $(document).on("click",".close", function (e) { //<--closest static element rather than document
                e.preventDefault();
                // $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
                $(this).closest(".dialog1").dialog("close");
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using the following code:

```
$("<div></div>")
    .addClass("dialog1")
    .attr("id", $(this).attr("id"))
    .appendTo("body")
    .css("background-color","red")
    .dialog({
            ...
```

Important is the `.css("background-color", "red")`line.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a change in the css itself

e.g. `.ui-dialog {background:yellow}`

Answer (score 0):

simplest way is to override the jquery dialog background property as below

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content {
        background: red;
    }
```